# windows onload - unobtrusively parsing value from form error

Tags: javascript

I currently have an onclick function within my html code which is an autocomplete function. My objective is to move all javascript out of the html into a separate file, however, the transfer is not working in this instance.

This works: It calls the function correctly

```
<form>  
<input class="input" id="location" onclick="showHint(this.value)" value=""/>
    <input class="input_submit" id="fj" type="submit" value="Find!"/>
</form>
```

This does not work (though it will show an alert box - so it is connecting)

```
<form>  
<input class="input" id="location" value=""/>
    <input class="input_submit" id="fj" type="submit" value="Find!"/>
</form>

window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("location").onclick = showHint(this.value);
}
```

I am pretty confident that (this.value) needs to be done in another way.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated.

RESULTS

So the code now works with this:

```
document.getElementById("location").onclick = function(){ showHint(this.value);};
```

When the above was originally suggested to me, it looks like I had an incorrect code somewhere in my JS file that prevented it from firing correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you provided and leaving your HTML the same, this should give you the results you are looking for:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var showHint = function(val){
        alert(val);
    };

    document.getElementById("location").onclick = function(){
        showHint(this.value);
    }; 
};
```

Here is a fiddle that shows the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/zsXw5/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Josh but unfortunately it doesn't. :/ Just to confirm that showHint is a large function that is being called based on what the user types in the box.

Comment: Are you trying to show hints as they type? Or when the form is submitted? The way your code is written right now, it only fires when they click on the input box... If there is nothing in the box, nothing shows up in the alert window... here is an example with a value: http://jsfiddle.net/zsXw5/1/

Comment: To have it fire as they type, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zsXw5/2/

Comment: Thanks @Josh-taylor, my code does also include an onkeyup, but I simplified my code to show what I wanted to achieve. My main function showHint should read whatever the user types and matches against a list and on finding matches brings in innerhtml. My function works within html, but the value is not getting passed to the function correctly when trying to move the code to be unobtrusive.

Comment: That is interesting. The functionality works in jsfiddle, and that is essentially the same as having the code in a separate file like you are trying to achieve. Where are you placing your script block? The only thing I can think is that perhaps the DOM is not fully loaded when you are subscribing the click or keyup event. Is your script block that references the external file at the bottom of your code or at the top? If at the top, try moving to just above the closing </body> tag and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I managed to get it to work by doing your above example, but omitting your window.onload section. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if `window` has an `onload` property. Even if so, the event handler has been long ago fired already when the JavaScript interpreter gets to assigning your function to it, thus your code will never be run.

Try putting your `onclick` initialization inside a `<script>` tag at the very end of `<body>` instead.

```
<!-- ... -->
    <script>    
        var locationElement = document.getElementById("location");
        locationElement.onclick = function() {
            showHint(locationElement.value);
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

Also, you could use **[jQuery](http://www.jquery.com)** and set this up as

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#location").click(function() {
        showHint($(this).val());
    });
}
```

This one is a bit more clean. In exchange you need the 3rd party lib.

Comment: For some reason your suggestion is not working for me.

Comment: Also it might be that `this` is bound to `window` (I don't remember, but it is likely) the scope you're setting up onclick handler at. Assign `document.getElementById("location")` to a variable and use that at the `onclick` line and the `showHint` line as well: `showHint(location.value);`. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Hmm...I wasn't aware that I had a JS console. Just to clarify I have only been learning javascript for fun within a matter of weeks (accumulatively a few hours!)

Comment: `CTRL + SHIFT + K` in Firefox, `CTRL + SHIFT + J` in Chrome, `F12` in IE.

Comment: No unfortunately. Still messing around with it. Of course it still works with the onclick="showHint(this.value)" within the html. Just can't fathom out why the unobtrusive won't work. I can't see why it should or would be any more complicated. The JS console doesn't seem to show any errors either.

Comment: @Tez I guess - in contrast to your posting - you have the script put correctly inside a `<script>` tag. Also, are you sure that `window.onload` is correct? And also, when you can attach the onload handler, it has already long ago fired, so it will be never run again. Try, instead of using `onload`, putting your init script in a `<script>` tag at the very end of `<body>`. I'll edit accordingly...

Comment: Thank you for all of your help. I think it was something silly in the end, and your originally suggestion was very close if not exactly what I needed. You've done that many edits now though (in vain to help me), that your original suggestion doesn't show. :)